# Spring: set Tomcat server root

Tags: spring, tomcat

I'm writing a Spring application where users may upload files which will later be served again.

However the directory in which the files will be stored is always a temporary location (per default), such as `/tmp/tomcat-docbase.XYZ`. So whenever the application is restarted, another path will be chosen and all the files uploaded before are lost.

I can't figure out how to set the server's root manually.
I tried setting the `server.tomcat.basedir` in my `application.properties` but this didn't do it (guess it is just the wrong property)..

So what did I miss? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The application should not leave the files in the temp directory but move them to a specific path when the transfer is completed

Comment: @SergeBallesta yeah, that would solve my specific problem but I mean there has to be a way to specify another path hasn't it?

Comment: Any other way would be a dirty hack. You should not care where the files are uploaded but move them (or store their content in a database or...) when done.

Comment: Ok, yeah makes sense to not bloat your server installation bot load the files on demand.
Thank you :)